# Any easy way to convert JSON into valid JSON (quotation, escaping...)?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a vague memory of using some kind of Strgingify/quote function, so when doing tests, you can format things like:

`"{ field : value, field2 : value }"`  and avoid having to backslash with quotes every field and value `"{ \"field\" : \"value\", \"field2\" : value }"`. So far I only found `JSONObject(X).toString()`, but it seems to escape chars from the values unintentionally (i.e, slashes from URLs).

Do you know any trick to obtain that need, preferrably with the JDK, Spring or Jackson, than using an external library. I would like to avoid replaces.

Comment: can you provide proper in- and outputs please? I don't understand completly what the desired result is

Comment: Thanks! you can see the expected result now

Comment: I assume you have a "Json" Data like `"{ field : value, field2 : value }"` and want it to be converted to a "String"? Your jsondata is in form of Map?

Comment: if it is in form of a map, you could just do some iteration and stringbuilder magic then it should be easy

Comment: But I remember some utils like JSON.validate() or JSONObject.parse() or JSONParser.fix(), some useful shortcut for this

Comment: Do you want to convert map to string or vice versa? There are APIs for it

Comment: My understanding is that instead of writing a well formed JSON string like `"{ \"field\" : \"value\", \"field2\" : \"value\" }"` you want to use a 'compressed form' of `"{ field : value, field2 : value }"` and expect a utility to convert it back to a well formed JSON. Am I right? How would this utility tell numbers, booleans and strings apart then? In other words how should it convert JSON values that wouldn't normally be quoted? It's impossible unless you only expect only string (and object) values in your JSON.

Comment: Exactly! Ok, then assuming I just quote values?